# Generating one new field in table (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have View where I create interview with greeting and details

Here is table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Interviews] (
[Interview_Id] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Greeting]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Detail]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[VacancyId]    INT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Interview_Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Interviews_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([VacancyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Vacancies] ([VacancyId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);

Here is my controller for this View

```
  // Страница ввода приветствия и описания вакансии
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen()
    {
        // Формируем список команд для передачи в представление
        SelectList teams = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        ViewBag.Teams = teams;

        return View();
    }


    //Заносим инфу о вакансии в таблицу
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen(Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Int32 id = interview.Interview_Id;
        //TempData["id"] = id;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new { id = interview.Interview_Id });
    }
```

Here is my View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="outer-div">
        <div class="inner-div">
            <div class="right-welcome-div">
                <div class="right-grid-in-grid">

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Vacancy.VacancyId, ViewBag.Teams as SelectList, new { @class = "greeting" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacancyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="main-left-div">

                    <div style="margin-left: 40px">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Greeting, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "greeting", data_bind = "textInput: Greeting", placeholder = "Приветствие", id="Greeting"}})
                    </div>

                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Detail, new { @class = "greeting2", data_bind = "textInput: Detail" })

                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="left-welcome-div">
                <div class="text-div" style="padding-top: 30px; word-break: break-all;">
                    <p style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 40px; text-align: center;"><b><span data-bind="text: Greeting"/></b>
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 40px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 40px; text-align: center;"><span data-bind="text: Detail"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="button-div" style="padding-top: 40px;">
                    <input  style="float: right; margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 20px; border-radius: 12px; width: 200px;" type="submit" value="Создать" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ViewModel() {
            this.Greeting = ko.observable('');
            this.Detail = ko.observable('');
        };

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);

    </script>
}
```

When I click submit button it creates new empty row in Vacancies table.

I don't understand, why??

Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you generate dropDownList with name Vacancy.VacancyId according the following code an it will create a instance of Vacancy in property of Interview and When you add Interview in dbContext, EF will create new row for Vacancy because interview.Vacancy is not null.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Vacancy.VacancyId, ViewBag.Teams as SelectList, new { @class = "greeting" })
```

Replace the code with this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VacancyId, ViewBag.Teams as SelectList, new { @class = "greeting" })
```

Comment: Thank's a lot dude.